# Error about 'CategoricalDtype' when importing Pandas on Raspberry PI

Tags: python, pandas, pip, raspberry-pi3

I am having errors getting Pandas installed on my PI

First ran:
sudo pip3 install pandas

Then this to get Numpy working:
sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev

Numpy can import now but I get the following error with Pandas:

```
    >>> import pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import pandas
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py",         line 42, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config_init
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-        packages/pandas/core/config_init.py", line 13, in <module>
        import pandas.core.config as cf
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-        packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 807, in <module>
        is_text = is_instance_factory((str, bytes))
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-        packages/pandas/core/config.py", line 778, in is_instance_factory
        from pandas.core.common import pprint_thing
      File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-        packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 23, in <module>
        from pandas.core.dtypes import CategoricalDtype,         CategoricalDtypeType, DatetimeTZDtype, DatetimeTZDtypeType
    ImportError: cannot import name 'CategoricalDtype'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your installation is broken... just uninstall and try again. If that doesn't work, try installing from source (Google it).

Comment: Tried to re-install but had the same error. Guess it's time to try from the source.